# In Appium, I am trying to access(tap a button or edit text in textfield) elements in webview using xpath. But i can't able to do

Tags: ios, xpath, acceptance-testing, appium-ios

In Appium, I am trying to access(i.e tap a button or edit text in a text field) elements in web view using XPath. But I am able to access native elements, not webview elements.

I got the XPath using the Appium inspector.

CONTEXT is "NATIVE" because when switched to "WEBVIEW" I'm getting HTML parsing error

```
XPATH : "//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name='Scripts: Responsive IFrames for embedding webpages']/XCUIElementTypeOther[8]/XCUIElementTypeTextView"



    /Users/dxcdr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/appium_lib_core-1.5.1/lib/appium_lib_core/common/wait.rb:96:in `until_true': timed out after 60 seconds (Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "The element '"Click to select all (also copies in IE)" Button' is not visible on the screen and thus is not interactable" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The element '"Click to select all (also copies in IE)" Button' is not visible on the screen and thus is not interactable}) (Appium::Core::Wait::TimeoutError)
        from /Users/dxcdr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/appium_lib_core-1.5.1/lib/appium_lib_core/common/wait.rb:127:in `wait_true'
        from /Users/dxcdr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/appium_lib-9.12.0/lib/appium_lib/common/wait.rb:26:in `wait_true'
        from /Users/dxcdr/RubymineProjects/Test/test.rb:53:in `wait_for_xpath_visible'
        from /Users/dxcdr/RubymineProjects/Test/test.rb:88:in `<top (required)>'
        from -e:1:in `load'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your locator is native-context like, not a html element inside web-view, e.g. `XCUIElementTypeOther` has nothing with webview elements
- You must switch to web view to be able search in it:

  web_view_context = available_contexts.find { |c| c.start_with? 'WEBVIEW' }

  set_context web_view_context
- Use [Safari debu](http://adaptivejs.mobify.com/v2.0/docs/debug-on-ios-devices-and-the-ios-simulator/)g to inspect element in webview

Comment: Luckily Appium Desktop 1.6 out. Now i can access webview elements via "NATIVE" context. Thanks @dmle